# jar file in Grails project lib directory not found

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a grails project and a jar file in the lib directory of the grails project. The problem is when i run the app I get class not found errors on classes within the jar file. Why can these not be seen by the grails app?

Answer (score 3):

From your last response, I believe you're missing some more required jar files. You should probably check if there are any other jars required for Esendex. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The lib directory is the right place for JAR files. With only the information provided above, I've no way of guessing why it's not working for you. All I can suggest is:

- Run "grails war" on the command line
- Unzip the created .war file and check that the JARs are in the WEB-INF\lib directory

If you're running Grails 1.2 you might want to check that the JAR isn't excluded by the new [dependency resolution DSL](http://www.grails.org/1.2+Release+Notes).

Comment: thanks - I'm trying to use Esendex from within a service in the grails-app/services directory.  I've got the Esendex jar in the lib folder and I've got the import line correct, it just throws a class def not found error on the Esendex Header class when i try to call the service.

Comment: I have done as you suggested - the corerct jars are within the WAR file in the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how the classes are used. Once you've added them to your lib directory, try updating the dependencies config in BuildConfig.groovy. Here's mine:

```
dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.
        runtime 'org.apache:commons-exec:1.1'
        runtime 'org.apache:httpcore:4.1.3'
        runtime 'org.apache:httpclient:4.1.2'
        runtime 'org.json:json:20080701'
        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.16'
    }
```

Comment: You've got a typo in your second dependency, "rutime".  :)